# C# : read json entries from a .log file with StreamReader and JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, streamreader

I'm new to C# and I want to read a `.log` file with json entries like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"
}

{
    "firstName": "Alice",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

I want to parse from "{" to "}" to get the beginning and end of one entry.

I used:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName);

logfile = sr.ReadLine();

var logentry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(logfile);
```

to deserialize the entry. It works well if the json entry is in one line. But the problem is that with `ReadLine()`, I can only read the json format in one line not multiple like the second example.

Maybe I could use `ReadToEnd()` and save it in a string and count the "{" and "}" and separate the entries.

Comment: If you're in control of stopping logs being written across multiple lines, I recommend you get onto that.

Comment: If size is not an issue you could probably try reading the whole file and separating entries using `string.Split()` by using a sequence like `"}\n"`. Not particularly, fast, cheap, or durable, but may work like a charm depending on your data set.

Comment: You could read the whole file and then use Regex to extract the json bits; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994677/find-json-strings-in-a-string

Comment: Set [`JsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm) as shown in [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063/3744182) and [Deserialize multiple json objects from a stream using Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48882653/3744182).

Comment: Thanks  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm is what is needed