# Unable to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject that is a list of just JSON objects no []

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

Using .Net C# and Newtonsoft JSON

I'm having considerable trouble deserialising a list of JSON objects from a vendor API that are not in an array or , delimited.   I'd like to deserialise them into a list but all attempts have only given errors

Example of list

```
{
    "reference": 12345,
    "recorded": 12345.0,
    "modified": 12345.0,
    "athleteReference": 12345,
    "athleteName": "Lipsum, Ipsum",
    "athleteWeight": 12.0,
    "exerciseName": "S",
    "exerciseReference": 12345,
    "barWeight": 12.0,
    "repCount": 12,
    "reps": [],
    "deleted": false
}
{
    "reference": 12345,
    "recorded": 12345.0,
    "modified": 12345.0,
    "athleteReference": 12345,
    "athleteName": "Lipsum, Ipsum",
    "athleteWeight": 12.0,
    "exerciseName": "S",
    "exerciseReference": 12345,
    "barWeight": 12.0,
    "repCount": 12,
    "reps": [],
    "deleted": false
}
{
    "reference": 12345,
    "recorded": 12345.0,
    "modified": 12345.0,
    "athleteReference": 12345,
    "athleteName": "Lipsum, Ipsum",
    "athleteWeight": 12.0,
    "exerciseName": "S",
    "exerciseReference": 12345,
    "barWeight": 12.0,
    "repCount": 12,
    "reps": [],
    "deleted": false
}
```

What is throwing me out is that these objects are not in [] nor any , between them. They appear as above using postman. I'm struggling to deserialise them into a List.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried deserialising into a response object List<>; however, I believe the lack of [] breaks this anyway.

Note the JSON from this API further deviates from standard JSON, and so the streamreader-based solutions offered although possibly viable if this JSON is kept to standard might work, they do not for me. I did not mention this since the initial issue was how to process this kind of Json.  However the answer was given with 'Line Json' mentioned I was able to work around with this without a streamreader.

Comment: Thats invalid JSON, plain and simple. In the real API response, are they formatted like that or maybe one object per line? If each are on a single line it would be fairly easy to just parse each line as a JSON object.

Comment: That's [line json](https://jsonlines.org/) and you should be able to split on newline and then deserialize each of them separately.

Comment: Line JSON ?  Interesting I'll try the splitting

Comment: Set `JsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729419) by Yuval Itzchakov to [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48883002/3744182) by Evk to [Deserialize multiple json objects from a stream using Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48882653/3744182) and you should be good to go. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'm going to resolve this. the suggested solutionions did not give the solution for a unrelated reason to the question ( the JSON is further non standard so I can not use streamreader based solutions )  However the  'Line Json' was the clue on what I needed to do to resolve this.